# What Java Garbage Collectors cleanup PermGen?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, permgen

List of Garbage Collectors:

- Serial GC
- Parallel GC
- Parallel Old GC
- Conc Mark Sweep GC
- G1 GC

I know that the Conc Mark Sweep GC supports cleaning up PermGen when you enable the ClassUnloading JVM option. Do other Garbage Collectors support cleaning up PermGen?

Reason: We use Spring, Hibernate, and Groovy that create a lot of Proxies and Perm Gen gets big.

Edit:
Should have mentioned that I am using Java 7. I'm aware of Java 8 removing Perm Gen and hopefully will upgrade sometime in the future. In the meantime, my question is regarding if the other garbage collectors support cleaning up PermGen other than Conc Mark Sweep.

- Serial GC
- Parallel GC (Believe -server uses this by default and confirmed that it cleans up perm gen)
- Parallel Old GC
- Conc Mark Sweep GC (Can clean perm gen using JVM flag)
- G1 GC

Comment: If you get OOME: PermGen space errors, then it's most probably due to memory leaks, not a faulty GC engine.

Comment: You could upgrade to Java 8, in which PermGen [has been removed](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All algorithms are cleaning PermGen, but

- not every GC cycle include PermGen cleaning
- CMS can clean PermGen **concurrently**, G1 have been requiring **stop-the-world Full GC** to unload classes (clean PermGen) until Java 8u40
- Java 8 have metaspace instead of PermGen, but it needs to be garbage collected too (otherwise you'll get OOME in metaspace)

I have been fighting OOME in PermGen quite a lot when I was actively used ClassLoaders to simulate multiple JVM in single process for test purposes. My conclusion: PermGen GC is just not very reliable. One run it works as expected, other it throws OOEM.

Comment: With CMS (enabled via `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`) you may need to add some JVM parameters to actually make it garbage collect the PermGen. I believe the most common is that you'd want to add `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`. Sometime you may also need `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` so I recommend adding that and watch stdout/stderr while starting.

Also agree with the non-predicability, at least with Parallell. CMS and G1 have been much more reliable for me, while working on my [ClassLoader Leak Prevention library](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention)

Answer (score -1):

The problem with perm gen is that it was not supposed to be dynamic, it was supposed to be static data, like classes and constants. But what we developers are doing with java are things like creating classes on the fly, redefining classes, etc which required a more dynamic usage of that space and that's why in the metaspace case, it has to be.

The biggest issues with perm gen and, going back to your question that IMO doesn't go away with metaspace is the creation and destruction of the class loaders as it is too easy to leak class metadata in ThreadLocals and other libraries loaded by other classloaders and that will leave live objects that cannot be reclaimed by any of the collectors that you use.

Nowadays all production garbage collectors clean up the metaspace, but, they are not bound to clean it with the same frequency as other memory regions